# Why my listview always reset when i scroll after change item listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have problem in my listview android.
I changed Imageview in single item listview.
but after I scroll listview, the single item is reset to back to the beginning.

How to fix it?

This part of my code, where I change `imageview`:

```
if( Jumlah_list_Data== 0){

        }
        else {

             JSONObject c = laporanListObj.getJSONObject(0);

              String jumlah_favorite = c.getString(ContentLaporanActivity.TAG_BANYAK_FAVORITE_LAPORAN);
              String status_favorite = c.getString(ContentLaporanActivity.TAG_STATUS_FAVORITE);

              if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
                    mHolder.jmlh_favorite.setText(jumlah_favorite);

                    if(status_favorite.equals("0")){

                        mHolder.favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_noactive);
                        mHolder.kat_favorite.setText("favorite");
                    }
                    else{

                        mHolder.favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_active);
                        mHolder.kat_favorite.setText("unfavorite");
                    }


                }


        }
```

Comment: try something like this in your jelly bean device scroll the contacts list or music list to middle and delete one item and then check what happened ?

Comment: this is problem in listview jelly bean ? not happened

Comment: u will observe that list will be scrolled back to first